Bedeutungen von "abtun"
Ich habe die Bedeutungen aus Duden und DWDS zusammengesetzt und Folgendes bekommen:

Die Hauptbedeutung: „Er tut das als unwichtig ab“, „Sie tat die Einwände mit einer Handbewegung ab“ usw.
Jemanden geringschätzig behandeln oder übergehen: „Sie hat ihn arrogant abgetan“.
Die wörtliche Bedeutung (bezeichnet in den beiden als umgangssprachlich): „Soll ich den Mantel abtun?“

Bedeutung 1 wird zweifellos häufig verwendet. Was haltet ihr jedoch von 2 und 3? Werden diese heute noch benutzt und wenn ja, in welchen Sprachstilen?
P.S. Wenn jemand Informationen zur Verwendung in Norddeutschland hat, insbesondere in Niedersachsen, wäre ich sehr dankbar.

Die dritte Bedeutung würde ich einer vergleichsweise niedrigen Sprachebene zuordnen. Ich jedenfalls wurde als Kind noch korrigiert mit Sprüchen wie "Man tut nicht tuen!". Man sagt also nicht (nach der damaligen Auffassung) "Ich tue den Ball weg", sondern zum Beispiel "Ich räume den Ball weg". Ähnlich würde ich "Ich tue den Mantel ab" einordnen. Wenn diese Bedeutung von "abtun" noch signifikant verbreitet ist, dann in Zusammenhängen (Regiolekte, Soziolekte o. ä.), wo "tuen" als Hauptverb üblich ist.

Der Duden kennt noch: töten - Gebrauch: schweizerisch, sonst veraltet, was (2) in ein leicht anderes Licht rückt....

@HenningKockerbeck Wenn man Gutes tun kann, warum nicht einen Mantel abtun?

Fall zwei klingt ein wenig merkwürdig/holperig vom Sprachgefühl. Das würde ich eher nutzen als "Sie hat ihn als arrogant abgetan". Es impliziert dann eine Bewertung der Person, die arrogant/unsympathisch ist ("ihn") und "Sie" hat deswegen beschlossen ihn zu ignorieren.
Alternativ könnte man in dem Satzbau verwenden: "Sie hat ihn arrogant abgefertigt". Dann bezieht sich das auf "Sie" und die Art wie sie mit "ihm" umgegangen ist.
Fall drei ist eine veraltete Form. So ähnlich hätte man wohl zu Kaiser Wilhelms Zeiten gesprochen. Eher geläufig heute wäre: "Soll ich den Mantel ablegen?" "Wo kann ich den Mantel ablegen?" (oder "ausziehen").

Zumindest für mich hat "Sie hat ihn arrogant abgetan" und "Sie hat ihn als arrogant abgetan" unterschiedliche Bedeutungen. Im ersten Fall ist "arrogant" ein Adverb, das die Handlung des "Abtuns" näher beschreibt. Im zweiten Fall ist "arrogant" ein Adjektiv, das sozusagen den Grund für ihre Ablehnung liefert. Im ersten Fall ist also sie die arrogante Person, im zweiten Fall er.

Ja, korrekt, das hab ich auch so gemeint.
